# retrieving data from the database and comparing the retrieved result in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conCTSystem"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conSchedule = new SqlConnection(strCon);

conSchedule.Open();

SqlCommand cmdSchedule = new SqlCommand("Select Day From Schedule Where RoomNumber=@roomNumber", conSchedule);
cmdSchedule.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomNumber", ddlRoomNumber.SelectedValue); //MatchWithDropDownList

using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSchedule))
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
       string ReturnDay = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Day"].ToString();

       if (ReturnDay == "Monday")
       {
          Label1.Text = "abc";
       }
       else
       {
          Label1.Text = "cde";
       }
    }
 }
```

Can anyone help me for solve this problem? I am a new learner for using asp.net c# and I face the problem is when the `ReturnDay` is equal to `Monday` and should displaying the "abc" result but the output is show to me was "cde".

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `string ReturnDay ...` and inspect the value of it. I suspect that it's not exactly `Monday`.

Comment: set a breakpoint to it, then look what it gives you back. edit: ah damn, too slow!

Comment: The value is exactly Monday..

Comment: @user3013794: So does the code enter the first block of the `if` statement? Then your code is not relevant to your issue and the reason can be found somewhere else. Maybe you are overwriting the text elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
if (ReturnDay.Trim().Equals("Monday"))
{
    Label1.Text = "abc";
}
```

or

```
if (ReturnDay.Trim().Equals("Monday",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Label1.Text = "abc";
}
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter: sir but OP is saying  he is getting Exactly `Monday`?

Comment: Problem Solve.. Thank @Sudhakar for helping and other

Comment: first one. Why required to use Trim()?

Comment: @user3013794 Trim() function would remove the whitespace chars from the begining and end of the string. accept the answer if it helps you.